# How to draw graphical primitives over pdf C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, graphics, itext

I have PDF document with text. My application based on WPF. I need open PDF, show in form, then user allocate zones and I need to read text from this zones. For this I use ItextSharp and check all charters. If charter in rectangle, it is writing to specific dictionary.

```
    List<List<ExtendedTextChunk>> ls = Reader.GetLocTextPDF(inp);
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> texts = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    Dictionary<string, RectangleJ> zones = new Dictionary<string, RectangleJ>()
    {
        { "test_zone", new RectangleJ(54,718,52,8) },
        { "document_number", new RectangleJ(507,612,57,7) },
    };
        texts.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
        for (int i = 0; i < ls[0].Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ls[0][i].Chars.Count; j++)
            {
                foreach (string zone in zones.Keys)
                {
                    RectangleJ a = ls[0][i].Chars[j].Location.Intersection(zones[zone]);
                    if (a.Width > 0 && a.Height > 0)
                    {
                        if (!texts[texts.Count - 1].ContainsKey(zone))
                            texts[texts.Count - 1][zone] = "";
                        texts[texts.Count - 1][zone] += ls[0][i].Chars[j].Text;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
    public class LocatedChar
    {
        public RectangleJ Location;
        public string Text;
    }
    public class ExtendedTextChunk
    {
        public List<LocatedChar> Chars = new List<LocatedChar>();
```

My problem is to get this rectangles from form by user. Sorry for bad english, and thank you for your time. =)